# angularjs bs-tabs title not showing up - [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to create tabs with bs-tabs with angular js. My problem is that the content is showing up correctly but the title isn't.

This is how my tabs in the controller look like:

```
 $scope.tabs = [
        {
            "title": "Allgemein",
            "content":"Test"
        },
        {
            "title": "Bedarf",
            "content": "Test2"
        },

        {
            "title": "Einsatz",
            "content": "Test3"
        },
        {
            "title": "Tätigkeiten",
            "content": "Test4"
        },
        {
            "title": "Ereignisse",
            "content": "Test5"
        },
        {
            "title": "Bemerkung",
            content: "Test6"
        },
        {
            "title": "Dokumente",
            "content": 'Test7'
        }];
```

and this is how I insert the tabs in the html file:

```
<div bs-tabs="tabs">

    </div>
```

Can somebody help me with the issue?

EDIT:

After looking further into it, I got this error message:

```
Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.
```

I am relatively new to angular and I have no clue what it means.
Thanks in advance

EDIT(Solved):

adding:

```
$sce.trustAsHtml
```

solved the issue

so a tab in the controller would look like this:

```
 {
            title: $sce.trustAsHtml("Allgemein"),
            content: $sce.trustAsHtml("Test")
 }
```

Comment: angular.module('test')
    .controller('MxjobdetailCtrl', function ($scope, $state, objectdetail, $stateParams, $log) {

is the controller itself and it's linked to the html via the route in the apps.js

the controller itself works very well, except for the tab controls

Comment: How your generated DOM look like? It's better to edit the question and include the code then add comment.

Comment: It is just the basic example. It should display the title, there is no modification what so ever to it. not on the fly, just on load. Basic titles and basic content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How to resolve "Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996899/angularjs-how-to-resolve-attempting-to-use-an-unsafe-value-in-a-safe-context)