# AngularJS: How to resolve "Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context"?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textarea

When I tried to show my data as a text-html, it displayed in HTML format but when I refreshed the page, I am getting this error:

> [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.

Here is my **AngularJS** code:

```
data.attributes.task_name = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.attributes.task_name);
```

**HTML**

```
<span ng-bind-html="taskdata.attributes.task_name" data-html="true" title="{{reminder.attributes.message}}"></span>
```

Comment: Does [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41997335/4927984) solved your issue?

Answer (score 56):

From the [**Angular documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/unsafe):

> The value provided for use in a specific context was not found to be
>   safe/trusted for use.
>
> AngularJS's [Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) mode (enabled by
>   default), requires bindings in certain contexts to result in a value
>   that is trusted as safe for use in such a context. (e.g. loading an
>   AngularJS template from a URL requires that the URL is one considered
>   safe for loading resources.)
>
> This helps prevent XSS and other security issues. Read more at [Strict
>   Contextual Escaping (SCE)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)
>
> You may want to include the `ngSanitize` module to use the automatic
>   sanitizing.

---

You have to include **[`ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)**:

Load it on **index.html**:

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

Inject it as a dependency in your **app.js**:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['...', 'ngSanitize']);
```

Comment: This did wonders to allow me to split-join a character with a linebreak in AngularJS. Thank you!

Comment: including ngSanitize fixed it for me! thanks!