# Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context on Angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$sce/unsafe
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:68:12
    at htmlSanitizer (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:18691:13)
    at getTrusted (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:18860:16)
    at Object.sce.(anonymous function) [as getTrustedHtml] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:19540:16)
    at ngBindHtmlWatchAction (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:25632:29)
    at Scope.$digest (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:17814:23)
    at Scope.$apply (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:18080:24)
    at bootstrapApply (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:1841:15)
    at Object.invoke (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4842:19)
    at doBootstrap (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:1839:14)
```

This is the error I get with the code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="parking">
<head>
<title>[Packt] Parking</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var parking = angular.module("parking", []);
    parking.controller("parkingCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.appTitle = "<b>[Packt] Parking</b>";
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="parkingCtrl">
<h3 ng-bind-html="appTitle"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to angular js. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How to resolve "Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996899/angularjs-how-to-resolve-attempting-to-use-an-unsafe-value-in-a-safe-context)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, you need to inject `$sce` in your controller. Then you have to instruct Angular to trust your content as HTML, like so:

```
var parking = angular.module("parking", []);
    parking.controller("parkingCtrl", function ($scope, $sce) {
        $scope.appTitle = "<b>[Packt] Parking</b>";
        $scope.trustedAppTitle = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.appTitle);
    });
```

And then you have to bind the HTML to the trusted variable, like so:

`<h3 ng-bind-html="trustedAppTitle"></h3>`

All in all, your code should look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="parking">
<head>
<title>[Packt] Parking</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var parking = angular.module("parking", []);
    parking.controller("parkingCtrl", function ($scope, $sce) {
        $scope.appTitle = "<b>[Packt] Parking</b>";
        $scope.trustedAppTitle = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.appTitle);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="parkingCtrl">
<h3 ng-bind-html="trustedAppTitle"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ReferenceError: $sce is not defined. This is what I get.Where should I place it?

Comment: I edited the code, I forgot to inject $sce in the last code snippet.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.. parking.controller("parkingCtrl", function ($scope, $sce) {

Answer (score 11):

Create a global filter injecting `$sce` to bind unsafe HTML from controller in view.

```js
var parking = angular.module("parking", []);
parking.controller("parkingCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.appTitle = "<b>[Packt] Parking</b>";
});

parking.filter('safeHtml', function ($sce) {
    return function (val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="parking">
<head>
<title>[Packt] Parking</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="parkingCtrl">
<h3 ng-bind-html="appTitle | safeHtml"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```