# angularjs: show a dropdown list on tablecell onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dropdown

i want to replace table cell value with a dropdownlist when i click on tablecell in angularjs. 
[so if i click 7114 it should change to a dropdownlist containing all VDN numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbMKW.png)

**HTML table:**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in responseData | groupBy: 'NameEn'">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr ng-repeat="responses in value">
                    <td>{{responses.vdnlanguage}}</td>
                    <td ng-click="editVDN()">
                        {{responses.vdnnum}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{responses.vdnname}}</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**AngularJs**

```
 $scope.editVDN = function () {
        alert("populate dropdownlist");

    }
```

Dropdownlist will be populated using response from an api. if anyone can help i will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Change `{{responses.vdnnum}}` to `<div ng-bind-html="responses.vdnnum"></div>`

`responses.vdnnum` should have the html string constructed.

Something like `$scope.responses.vdnnum = '<select><option>First</option></select>';`

The code should like this finally alongwith ng-bind-html:

```
$scope.editVdn = function () {
 $scope.responses.vdnnum = '<select><option>First</option></select>
};
```

Comment: Thanks @gauravmuk for reply. i have tried your solution but it didnt work. i am getting two type of errors. 1. Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context. 2. Cannot set property 'vdnnum' of undefined at ChildScope.$scope.editVDN. is there anything else we are missing?

Comment: you will need to inject $sce as well first. have you done that? to solve the second issues do this, $scope.responses = $scope.responses || {}; before setting the $scope.responses.vdnnum

Comment: for the first problem, this would be better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996899/angularjs-how-to-resolve-attempting-to-use-an-unsafe-value-in-a-safe-context

Comment: ok i have resolved the errors but cell is not changing to dropdownlist. if i am not wrong ng-html-bind will change the cell to select tag. yes?

Comment: i am getting vdnnum value as "<select><option>1111</option><option>1112</option></select>" but its not chnaging on click

Comment: yes, can you create a fiddle? what is the current statement of your html? ng-bind-html="htmlDom" in html and in controller, $scope.htmlDom = '<div></div>'; or the dropdown html you have

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11942/)  here is fiddle. but it does not have angular-filter.js thats why its throw an error but hopefully you will get an idea. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So i found a solution i thought it might be helpful for someone else. following is the code which i have coded to resolve the issue.

```
<td  ng-click="mode = 'edit'">
    <span ng-show="mode == edit">{{responses.vdnnum}}</span>
    <select ng-show="mode != edit" ng-options="option.vdnname for option in responseData track by option.id"
        ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="selectedItemChanged(selectedOption)" class="form-control selcls" style="width:250px;">
        <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
    </select>
</td>
```