# Angular compile returned data and then trust it not working

Tags: angularjs

Im getting some data and then trying to compile it and then "trust" the content as HTML and then assign the data to `scope.model` but its for some reason yelling at me saying: `Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html`

```
if (response.data) {
   var trustedData = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.PostContent);

   scope.model.postContent = $compile(trustedData);
}
```

Comment: $sce.trustAsHtml must receive a string

Comment: You should first do `$sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.PostContent);` and then compile the result in to the DOM.

Comment: @nicolascolman right, i know that. However i MUST compile the incoming HTML data so angular can inject data into the custom elements. Then i need to trust the html content and spit it out to the page

Comment: @lealceldeiro if i do it that way i get `Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.`

Comment: Myabe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996899/angularjs-how-to-resolve-attempting-to-use-an-unsafe-value-in-a-safe-context

Comment: @lealceldeiro right i tried sanitizing it and then all the outputs look like 
`function (scope) { var elt = link.apply(this, arguments); var descriptor = scopeDescriptor(elt, scope); hint.emit('scope:link', { id: scope.$id, descriptor: descriptor }); return elt; }`

Comment: Did you include angular-sanitize.js?

Comment: @nicolascolman of course i linked to it with a CDN

Comment: You should post the complete code or at least the most relevant parts.